# Javascript digital timing in a form

Tags: javascript

The script below displays a static date and Time.

**How do I make the hours, minutes and seconds dynamic?**

I want to show digital time changes (as on an electronic watch).

I'm passing the variable in a form.

```
<input id="date1" name="date1">

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds()

document.write(month + "-" + day + "-" + year+ "-" + hours+ "-" + minutes+ "-" + seconds)

document.getElementById('date1').value = (month + "-" + day + "-" + year+ "-" + hours+ "-" + minutes+ "-" + seconds);
</script>
```

Comment: @Soviut the code is posted right there

Comment: Why use a form at all? Check out [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) or [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).

Comment: `setInterval` is probably where you'd want to start.

Comment: No, that's a very old script that was copied and pasted and doesn't even attempt to do what the OP asked.

Comment: @DaveNewton you should write an actual answer, don't use comments for answering questions.

Comment: @Soviut Thanks for the input. Rather than providing an answer on a plate, particularly when people are starting out, I'd rather provide starting points so they can progress further on their own and place the onus back on the OP. YMMV. Also, it's hard to write code examples on a phone.

Comment: @DaveNewton I agree but you can do that in an actual answer instead of polluting the comments with partial answers. They're supposed to be for getting clarification from the OP. Comments can't be as easily curated so a lot of misinformation is stagnating in them on SO as a result.

Comment: @Soviut Not really, no; a link to `setInterval` docs and a trivial example (besides being annoying to type on mobile) is not a sufficient answer since it is incomplete. "Comments" are generic--they have no single purpose. Feel free to flag my comments and take it up on meta--this seems far more polluting than a hint regarding the direction to take.

Answer (score 0):

**Use setInterval()**

An easy way to do it is to use setInterval() with an interval of 1 second (1000ms) which will cause your code to be executed every 1 second:

```html
<input id="date1" name="date1">

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

setInterval(function(){
  var currentTime = new Date()
  var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
  var day = currentTime.getDate()
  var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
  var hours = currentTime.getHours()
  var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
  var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds()
  document.getElementById('date1').value = (month + "-" + day + "-" + year+ "-" + hours+ "-" + minutes+ "-" + seconds);
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: won't this interval call drain system resources and battery

Comment: I'm not sure why do you think that it will?

Answer (score 0):

This will refresh your time every second:

```js
    setInterval(function showTime() {
        var currentTime = new Date();
        var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
        var day = currentTime.getDate();
        var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
        var hours = currentTime.getHours();
        var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
        var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();

        document.getElementById('date1').value = (month + "-" + day + "-" + year + "-" + hours + "-" + minutes + "-" + seconds);
    }, 1000);
```

```html
<body>
<input id="date1" name="date1">
```